# edit files in git repo via browser

Tags: git

I use git for all of my projects and papers.  Sometimes I'm away from my machines, but would like to work on something in a git repo.  I've see gitweb which allows me to *view* files in a git repo that is sitting on my web server.  Is there anything (cgi scripts or some such thing) that would allow me to point any browser at my web server so that I can edit and commit files (similar to what github provides, but on my own machine)?

Comment: AFAIK, no web interface provides that functionality. Why don't you use GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a list of [known git frontends](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools#WebInterface) which you can sift through, but I can't find one myself.

If you eliminate integrating git then the question becomes "how do I edit files remotely" which is much simpler and has the same effect.  You could simply ssh into your machine and edit them, or you can remote mount the directory and edit them locally.  A number of good editors have the ability to remote edit over ssh and ftp as well as interact with git.  And I'm sure there's any number of web interfaces that let you edit files (though the security implications would make me be careful about that).

Or you can bypass the remote editing altogether.  Just `git clone` your project to the machine you're working at and work on it.  Put a copy of git and your favorite editor on a USB stick and you're ready to roll.

The advantage of these approaches is you're not limited to what the git interface can do.

Or can use [github](http://github.com).  Assuming this is not public information, you can buy an account with private repositories for $7/month.  The advantage of this approach is you don't have to admin it and the github folks will probably do a better job.

Answer (score 2):

[Codiad](http://codiad.com/) lets you edit files, and has some kind of Git support.
I'm also looking for something similar but haven't tested it's Git support yet. Maybe something can work out of it.

Ok, well, the "Git support" seems to be nothing more than a plugin that allows you to "pull git repositories". Maybe I was being too hopeful.